# What can I do with my newly aquired hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

I have just aquired a new hat as a part of the [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/) celebrations.

I was wondering, what can be done with my hat?

I have worked out I can wear it, take it off, admire it in my collection of hats, and feel smug about having a hat.

- Are there any other things that this hat can be used for?
- Can I turn it over and use it to busk for rep?
- Do different hats have different uses?

Comment: You only posted this for another free hat, didn't you? :P

Comment: "Can I turn it over and use it to busk for rep?". This is sad. Do you remember your reputation doesn't really mean much more than some virtual hats ? Just wear it and dive in the snow !

Comment: @dystroy Atleast rep won't disappear in a few weeks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about:

- Bragging about it
- Complimenting other users for their hats
- Try to collect them all
- Find a suitable gravatar to fit with the hat
- Thank the developers for including a piece of joy into our life

Remember, the christmas thought, it is not about the food and the presents, it is about caring for each other and having a good time.

Comment: Joy??? More like stress. Now I am freaking out about getting all these stupid hats at 3am.

Answer (score 8):

No, it's just a decoration to your gravatar. Nothing more, nothing less.

Other users might admire you for having a nice or secret hat.

You might attract more women this way if you choose the proper hat. :-)

Comment: I hope not, one woman is more than enough ;-).

Comment: "you might attract more women" - genius :-)

Comment: So @Rory can you confirm this is true? :-D

Comment: I went for the mask option and can confirm it is absolutely true: https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/37325_115001245213753_6131083_n.jpg

Answer (score 6):

Read [Winter Bash FAQ](http://winterba.sh/faq) and you will know what you can do.